# Numbered options for bash completion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Can we get numbered completion options with bash when we have started typing part of the option? For example with ksh I am able to get a numbered list of options and then when I press 3 followed by 3 I get the 3rd option completed.

```
> cat local.
1) local.cshrc
2) local.login
3) local.profile
> cat local.profile
```

Is this kind of completion possible using bash programmable completion?

With something like this I am able to give numbers for all available options, but this breaks when the user starts to type the option and presses tab so a fallback to normal options without numbers has to be used.

```
(( COMP_CWORD > 2 )) && return #This stops completion at third word for z oe
if [[ "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" = "" || $( echo "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" | perl -ne 'use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number); if (looks_like_number($_)){print 1}else{print 0}' ) -eq 1 ]]; then
    #Show all instances oratab + running
    local suggestions=($( compgen -W "$( { z ot | grep -v ^$ | grep -v SIDs | grep -v : && z p1; } | perl -lpe 's/\s+$//' | sort | uniq | perl -ne 'print "$.) $_"' )" -- "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" ))

    if [ "${#suggestions[@]}" == "1" ]; then #One match found
        local cmd=$( echo "${suggestions[0]}" | perl -pe 's/[1-9]+\)[\s]+//' )
        COMPREPLY=("$cmd ") #Space needed here to handle -o nospace
        return
    else
        #More than one suggestions resolved, respond with the suggestions intact
        COMPREPLY=("${suggestions[@]}")
        return 
    fi    
else 

    local suggestions=( $( compgen -W "$( { z ot | grep -v ^$ | grep -v SIDs | grep -v : && z p1; } | perl -lpe 's/\s+$//' | sort | uniq )" -- "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" ) )

    if [ "${#suggestions[@]}" == "1" ]; then #One match found
        local cmd="${suggestions[0]}"
        COMPREPLY=("$cmd ") #Space needed here to handle -o nospace
        return
    else
        #More than one suggestions resolved, respond with the suggestions intact
        COMPREPLY=("${suggestions[@]}")
        return
    fi                
fi
```

Is there way to do the ksh like completion number + tab with bash completion?

Comment: you can add the number prefix when generating `COMPREPLY` and remove the number prefix in the end.

Comment: Thanks pynexj that's what I am doing now... But ksh has this way of adding numbers after partial word is typed as well and the option can be selected by using the number and tab

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but the [`menu-complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html) completion function supports a numeric argument, which skip ahead that many options. I *think* the argument has to be provided at `bind` time, so it's not an out-of-the box solution, but might be a helpful pointer.